# Can you download GitBook Files and Directories?

Tags: git, github, webhooks, gitbook

**GitBook** allow `content` transfers into different formats but is there an option to download **files & directories** as they are edited (as text)?

By example, **GitHub** `code` is stored on servers and locally on contributor's PCs too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Current Answer, Posted On June 22nd 2022**

According to [a comment by Paul Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908504/can-you-download-gitbook-files-and-directories/34979942?noredirect=1#comment128420274_34979942), the ability to `git clone` GitBook repositories has either been removed or moved to a different URL.

When I logged into  gitbook.com, there is an option to "synchronize with Git" using either GitHub or GitLab. As I don't use GitBook much anymore, I cannot investigate how this feature work, but I assume this is currently the 'recommended' approach - connect GitBook over to either GitHub or GitLab, and then `git clone` the repository from that site.

[image: Selecting the "Synchronize with Git" Option]

[image: Choosing how to "Synchronize with Git"]

**Original Answer, Last Edited on Jan. 27th 2018**

Yes. You can *clone* the git repository where the GitBook resides on.

To clone the repository onto a local PC, type:

```
git clone https://git.gitbook.com/YOUR-USER-NAME/YOUR-BOOK-NAME.git
```

You will be prompted for your username for gitbook, and your password or an access token (i.e, an API Key). If you do not have a password, you may look up your unique access token in Settings -> Applications/Tokens.

You may also clone your git repository onto GitHub, but when you do so, GitHub will also ask for GitBook's username and password/access token so that it can read from Gitbook's git repository and just copy everything over. So you still need to have your username and your password/access token handy.

---

EDIT: When this answer was first written in January 2016, there was no official link to the `git` repository, making this an undocumented feature. Since then, the Gitbook team has exposed the URL to the `git` repository via its UI, as can be seen in this picture.

[image]

Comment: don't know why not developers of gitbook put the repo path on a marked place so people can clone their book repo easily...

Comment: @Chad You took the words out of my mouth. I guess the web traffic is more profitable for them. I guess at least it's possible, unlike a lot of "captive user interfaces" (as Gancarz puts it in his excellent book).

Comment: For me, username didn't work but email address did when performing `git clone`.

Comment: actually, it's better to just store the source on Github and have it sync. But it's not as straightforward to set this up as it should be.

Comment: Sadly in 2022 git clone https://git.gitbook.com/YOUR-USER-NAME/YOUR-BOOK-NAME.git no longer seems possible. git.gitbook.com isn't even a hostname anymore.